# SSH access of my VPS server

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I am using a VPS ubuntu server where I have installed fail2ban. I disabled root login and disabled access by password. Today having seen my auth.log and fail2ban status, I am worried if somebody got access to my system.

I have also seen my ssh connection to get disconnected telling that port reset by SOME_IP. One more thing that I have observed is my working directory path changes from root@ubuntu-1:/home/dadu# to root@ubuntu-1:/home/dadu# (i.,e. twice) when I enter clear command.

I am new to ubuntu.Please tell me whether or not somebody got access to my system.

````
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     119
|  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     2
   `- Banned IP list:   185.43.209.173


root@ubuntu-1:/home/dadu# sudo fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:      1
`- Jail list:   sshd


root@ubuntu-1:/home/dadu# sudo tail /var/log/auth.log
Sep 10 20:13:24 ubuntu-1 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user dadu by (uid=0)
Sep 10 20:13:24 ubuntu-1 systemd-logind[895]: New session 94 of user dadu.
Sep 10 20:13:45 ubuntu-1 sudo:     dadu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/dadu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
Sep 10 20:13:45 ubuntu-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dadu(uid=0)
Sep 10 20:13:45 ubuntu-1 su[9436]: Successful su for root by root
Sep 10 20:13:45 ubuntu-1 su[9436]: + /dev/pts/0 root:root
Sep 10 20:13:45 ubuntu-1 su[9436]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by dadu(uid=0)
Sep 10 20:13:45 ubuntu-1 su[9436]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Sep 10 20:15:19 ubuntu-1 sudo:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/dadu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log
Sep 10 20:15:19 ubuntu-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dadu(uid=0)
Sep 10 20:25:05 ubuntu-1 sshd[9899]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 112.123.58.229 port 59061: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Sep 10 20:29:13 ubuntu-1 sshd[22499]: Received disconnect from 218.98.26.181 port 31528:11:  [preauth]
Sep 10 20:29:13 ubuntu-1 sshd[22499]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 218.98.26.181 port 31528 [preauth]
Sep 10 20:30:12 ubuntu-1 sudo:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/dadu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client status sshd
Sep 10 20:30:12 ubuntu-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dadu(uid=0)
Sep 10 20:30:12 ubuntu-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 10 20:32:38 ubuntu-1 sshd[22552]: Received disconnect from 218.98.40.139 port 35499:11:  [preauth]
Sep 10 20:32:38 ubuntu-1 sshd[22552]: Disconnected from 218.98.40.139 port 35499 [preauth]
Sep 10 20:34:22 ubuntu-1 sudo:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/dadu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail /var/log/auth.log
Sep 10 20:34:22 ubuntu-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by dadu(uid=0)```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided evidence (or reason to believe) your system has been hacked.  When you disable ssh as root, you are preventing people from logging in to SSH using a root account.

What has happened here is someone - dadu (which I gather is you) has escalated their privileges to root in order to do some things - this is not an abnormal thing to do.    If you have used any commands/scripts which use  "su" and "sudo ..." then this is you. If you are sure that neither you, nor anyone you have authorised has issued a command then your system is likely compromised.  Of-course, fail2ban needs to run as root, so if you installed that (or did any system-wide software upgrade or the like) that is a likely explanation.

root@ubuntu-1:/home/dadu# appearing multiple times is not indicative of a compromise, rather a bug/trivially wrong configuration setting in your windowing/bash environment, and not worth worrying about.

Comment: The log shows that he ran `sudo su` and this is why he is root.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing special in your messages from auth.log.

To examine who had connected to your Linux system you use the "last" command. Try "last -iwn10". See "man last" for explanation.

If there are only lines you can attribute to legitimate actions, you shouldn't worry about SSH abuse (or any other where system login is involved).

Having said that, I should note that one should never rely on local logs of potentially compromised system, because attacker could have been tampered with them. This applies no only to Linux, but to absolutely any computer system.

To be sure one could do some preparations beforehand. For example, they could install secure logging server and configure server in question to send all system logs remotely to that logging server. Then, even if attacker had penetrated into server and erased their appearance from local logs, their appearance will still be evident from logs collected on the remote logging server. Still there are some issues, but I don't feel the need to go deeper into details.